# Facebook not recoginizing OG meta and returning redirct could not be followed

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-opengraph, meta

I have a site that is dealing me fits and I have tried everything I can think of. The problem is when you enter a url from the site in a Facebook post, it doesn't show a thumbnail option. I have a plugin that is providing the correct og meta data, but Facebook isn't recognizing it. I tried the Facebook debugger and it tells me that URL requested a HTTP redirect, but it could not be followed. I have no idea what is going on with this site and my client is very dependent of the traffic generated from Facebook. Can anyone tell me what is going on, please? Any post url on the site is causing the same problems.

Site is birminghammommy.com

One of the urls not working is http://www.birminghammommy.com/2012/04/paint-the-town-red-birmingham/

Any help you guys are able to provide will be greatly appreciated.

Keith
khcreativemedia.com

Comment: What is in your `.htaccess` file, anything wrong there ?

Comment: I'm sorry Sheikh, I missed your question earlier. My .htaccess file has# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

Answer (score 0):

Open Graph tags must be like this:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock" />
```

but if you look at your site you will see that your tags are wrong

```
<meta name='og:title' content='Paint the Town Red, Birmingham!' />
```

try fixing them.

Comment: Thanks, but I actually started out with them as property and changed them to name due to a suggestion a read on another site. I just changed them back, although I don't thing that is the problem.

Comment: Actually, I missed the single quote, double quote part of your response. I'll try that and respond back. Although I'm also getting the "URL requested a HTTP redirect, but it could not be followed" error which will be unrelated to the OG meta data, if you know an answer for that.

Comment: OK, I added the double quotes instead of singe quotes to all the og meta data and also change name to property. Facebook is still not recognizing it. Any ideas?

Thanks again for your help.
Keith

Comment: I don't know the problem exactly but I found out that your page doesn't redirect every time. Just go to [link](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.birminghammommy.com%2F2012%2F04%2Fpaint-the-town-red-birmingham%2F). If you get HTTP 320 response refresh page, try this until you get HTTP 200 response. But there is still a problem that your facebook application's(app id:101674015889) domain doesn't match your site.

Comment: Are you using GoDaddy to host your site? Google `GoDaddy 302 redirect problem` and you will see that there are people other than you facing the same problem.